# what's the best practice to add tags into the array using append? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

let's say I have an array like this which is being append into the ul like below

```
data['productDetailOptions'] = ['red', 'blue', 'big', 'small', 'medium'];

$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul').append(data['productDetailOptions']);
```

what's going on above does not have the `li` tag I know that for sure I can use a for loop to loop through each array and add the tag then assign them into a new variable.

I am wondering if there's an easier and shorter way so I don't have to use a loop?

EDIT: My bad, I should say any other ways than using a for loop.  Sorry for misunderstandings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `.map` method for every array, so the most efficient way for me looks like this :

```
$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul').append(data['productDetailOptions'].map( item => "<li>"+item+"</li>" ) );
```

Note: I'm using ES6 arrow functions. Which has it's equivalent :

```
$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul')
    .append( data['productDetailOptions'].map( function(item) { 
        return "<li>"+item+"</li>" 
    } ) );
```

Note 2 : Thanks for the comment by @Dora. Actually `$(..).append` [accepts both Array and string](http://api.jquery.com/append/), so the `.join` is unnecessary.

Comment: The `.map()` function is still a loop

Comment: Anything involving turning an array into a string is going to be a loop.  It's just wither or not you are writing it or it is built in. @ValLeNain

Comment: why is this voted a negative? and I am wondering the way it's being written is using es6 instead of 5 right? sorry still quite new for all these

Comment: ES6 it is. Will append this to my answer.

Comment: I did not add the `join("")` though and still append well, is there a huge difference if I don't use the `join()`? I would like your answer more esp you posted both es6 and es5 ways

Comment: I updated my answer. You are right. It works without join as well.

Answer (score 4):

Can use join() without writing your own loop to produce an html string you can append

```
var html = '<li>' + data['productDetailOptions'].join('</li><li>') + '</li>';

$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul').append(html);
```

Comment: can you please make me understand . what's going on ?

Comment: @Mahi start by reading [join() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). The delimiter goes between each array element ... so you are missing the initial opening and closing tag and add those on each end. I know it looks strange but it is correct as posted

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you call `.append()` as little as possible so that the DOM doesn't undergo unnecessary changes. So, you'd need to build up a string and then inject that just once like this:

```
// The .map() array method loops over the original array and creates a new
// one with content that is determined by the function passed to .map()
var htmlList = data['productDetailOptions'].map(item => "<li>" + item + "</li>" );


$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul').append(htmlList );
```

Comment: actually not that critical in a loop appending....browser won't repaint each iteration. I used to think the same but when you study more about browser rendering will find out it's not that big a deal when it's done quickly

Comment: @charlietfl You'll need to provide some resource to qualify that statement because I believe you are mistaken. Simple tests on this show that DOM modifications in loops are quite expensive.

Comment: been looking but I know I watched a video a couple of years regarding intelligent reflows and there was a minor wait time to see if anything was added and if it was there was another lag. May have changed over time and I could be totally wrong now

Comment: I can't speak to what you saw, but anytime you modify the DOM structure, such that you are modify the visible aspect(s) of a document, you will cause a reflow and a repaint.

Comment: right but the concept that I understaood *"at that time"* was that to minimize cpu , memory etc there was an intelligent lag albeit very tiny to allow for such instances . Again that might be old news and strategy changed. The temr used was something like intelligent repaint/reflow

Comment: I can't say that something like that was never attempted, but it actually wouldn't make sense to build that into the engine because you'd essentially be adding a deliberate bottle-neck (however small) into the performance of an application. Regardless, this is not how modern user agents work and, as such, DOM modifications should never be done in a loop.

Comment: but the thinking was the opposite to avoid too many repaints. I agree with you the do it once does seem to make more sens though. It was something that surprised me enough to remember it because it went against common sense but could also be like politicians .... out with the old in with the new cycle

Comment: would have also been either jsut before html5 got browser traction or slightly after it ...and that brought a lot of new engine requirements in. Also mentioned that a human can only see so many frames/sec

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `data['productDetailOptions']` elsewhere you can directly write the `<li>your content</li>` inside the array.
Like

```
data['productDetailOptions'] = ['<li>red</li>', '<li>blue</li>' /* ... */ ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` as well.

```
$('.cart-productDetailOptions ul')
    .append( data['productDetailOptions'].reduce( function(result, item) { 
        return result + "<li>" + item + "</li>" 
    }, "" ) );
```

To me it has better readability and `.reduce` has pretty [good support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)